# Matplotlib histtype='stepfilled' glitch

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

I'm plotting some histograms and having trouble with the `histtype=stepfilled`. The filling curve has obviously some wrong anchor points:

[image: matplotlib histogram with histtype='stepfilled' glitches]

Or am I missing some settings?

The code is pretty straight forward:

```
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.hist(self._neutrinoEnergies, histtype='stepfilled', color=colors.pop())
ax2.set_title(r'Neutrino Energies')
ax2.set_xlabel(r'$E_\nu$')
ax2.set_ylabel('count')
ax2.set_yscale('log')
```

Btw. if I set `histtype='bar'`, there are no bars at all (although it works if I do not set the yscale to `'log'`):

[image: matplotlib histogram with histtype='bar' does not show bars]

Comment: what version of mpl are you using?  There was alot of work on this that went into (I think) the most recent bug-fix release (1.2.1).  If it isn't there, it is definitely on master.

Comment: Yea, it's obviously a bug… I'm using mpl 1.0.1, since it's the newest version on our cluster.

Comment: You can either compile a local version of the newer code, or monkey patch the library.  I saw the fixes go by, they are related to how values with nonsensical log values (`log(0)` or `log(-1)`) are handled .

Comment: Yea, thanks for pointing it out! Unfortunately the file count quota is ridiculously low, so I maybe patching would be an idea… But Nic Eggerts solution works fine.

Comment: yeah, I knew a bunch of work had been done, but wasn't sure of the scope (Nic also a bunch of other histogram stuff).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matplotlib is trying to fill all the way down to 0, but 0 is always off the axes on a log scale (because log(0) is negative infinity).

The fix is calling `ax2.set_yscale('log', nonposy='clip')`. The change in 1.2.1 was so that this happens automatically when you call `hist(..., log=True)`. If you set the scale manually as you're doing, you always need the `nonposy='clip'`.